# (Pandas) Is there a faster way to find the indexes of all values in a row which are equal to the max in that row in pandas?

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a pandas dataframe Cellvoltage with multiple columns of float values. I'm trying to get the indices of all the values that equal the max value for every row.

So to achieve that, I am using the following code:

```
req_indices = np.argwhere(Cellvoltage.values == np.amax(Cellvoltage.values, axis=1).reshape(-1,1))
max_voltage_idx = [0]*len(req_indices)
for x,y in req_indices:
    if max_voltage_idx[x] == 0:
        max_voltage_idx[x] = [y]
    else:
        max_voltage_idx[x].append(y)
Cellvoltage['max_voltage_idx']  = pd.Series(max_voltage_idx).apply(np.array)
```

Is there a better/faster way to achive the same goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)` with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) to mask the non-max values, then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to remove the NaNs and get the index pairs.

```
out = df.where(df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)).stack().index.tolist()
```

Example input:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  3
1  4  1  1  4
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'C'), (0, 'D'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'D')]
```

If you want only the columns in a list as new column add a [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) step:

```
df['max_voltage_idx']= (df                  
   .where(df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)).stack()
   .reset_index(-1).iloc[:, 0]
   .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
 )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D max_voltage_idx
0  1  2  3  3          [C, D]
1  4  1  1  4          [A, D]
```

Comment: Renaming the columns as indexes gives me exactly what I want with this solution. This is definitely more elegant. However from some testing, I've done, this is slower. Putting it here just for the record.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
indices = np.where(df.values == np.amax(df.values, axis=1)[:, None])
list(zip(indices[0], df.columns.values[indices[1]]))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'C'), (0, 'D'), (1, 'A'), (1, 'D')]
```

Input:

The same @mozway (to whom I thank) uses:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  3
1  4  1  1  4
```